# How to load pickle files independent from any current implementation?

Tags: python, oop, pickle

### Remade Post:

Let's say I have a pickle file with an instance of a custom class inside. However, I do not have the source code of that class anymore (or only a modified one, which will not match).

Since the pickle file seems to know the class name and all the attribute names and values (otherwise it could not reconstruct the object in the first place) - is there any chance to retrieve all that information?

### Original Post:

> Assume we have a class definition like this:
>
> ```py
> class Foo:
>     class Bar:
>         def __init__(self, _):
>             pass  # Imagine some implementation
>
>     def __init__(self, a):
>         self._a = Foo.Bar(a)
> ```
>
> Then we instantiate it and dump the object into a file using pickle.
>
> ```py
> import pickle obj = Foo('whatever') pickle.dump(obj,
> open('./tmp.pkl', 'wb'))
> ```
>
> Now suppose we make changes in the naming or structure of our class
> (in this example, "Bar" is renamed to "Baz").
>
> ```py
> class Foo:
>     class Baz:
>         def __init__(self, _):
>             pass  # Imagine some implementation
>
>     def __init__(self, a):
>         self._a = Foo.Baz(a)
> ```
>
> If we finally try to load our dumped object in this context, like
> this:
>
> ```py
> obj = pickle.load(open('./tmp.pkl', 'rb'))
> ```
>
> We will get us an...
>
> ```
> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Foo.Bar' on <module
> '__main__' from 'myscript.py'>
> ```
>
> Question: Is there a way to load the pickle object independent from
> the current implementation of "Foo"? Since we have the `__dict__`
> attribute in Python, I thought there might be an option to get the
> pickled object as such a dict?

Sorry to everyone who has already answered, but the example I have given seems to be too complicated and distracting.

Comment: `pickle` simply does not store actual class or function definitions - that would be disastrous, you'd never be able to fix bugs or add features!  It simply stores the module and name where the definition was found.  In order to unpickle a file containing references to `Foo.Bar` objects, you must have a definition for `Foo.Bar` - although that could be a dummy class with a `__new__()` that creates an equivalent `Foo.Baz` object.

Comment: And - do you really need a nested-class design in Python? That is of very little use - some projects do use that for adding metainformation for the outside class, and a pseudo-out class can be good sometimes for namespacing (but a module would generally be better). You can always associate an instance of another class as an instance attribute in a class, without its definition being nested at all.

Comment: In this particular case, the information about the _nested_ class "Bar" is not even included in the serialization of an _instance_ of "Foo". Just an attribute of that instance being an instance of "Bar" will resolve to Python trying to read `Foo.Bar` to rebuild that instance.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I edited the post because of the distracting example - the actual question was more simple (won't mean the answer is simple, of course)

Comment: Just found [pickletools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickletools.html), which seems to be an easy way to get into whats in my pickle file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31322691/14326433) for more elaboration on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP:

#### For everyone facing similar issues, here is what I learned from this:

On live systems that will have changes in code along the way, I will from now on **avoid to `pickle.dump` custom objects**. Just because it is so vulnerable to changes in its source code.

#### Instead:

From now on, I will just extract essential data about my object into built-in data structures (for example `dict`) and pickle that. Adding a custom dumper and loader to my class is quite trivial, after all.

In case of any pickle-breaking changes in my source code, I can simply remap the old data to the desired new ones.

Hope this helps future frustration-plagued pickle users :)

Answer (score 1):

Apart of the very questionable nested-classes design, Python serialization through Pickle is quite customizable.

It is possible, for example, to write a a `__setstate__` method that will be called to assign values to a reconstructed class, when unpickling.

It would not help in this case, though - because Python would first try to unsreialize the nested attributes  -the `self._a` "Foo.Bar" instance, and only then try to create a new `Foo` instance, setting the `._a` value.

You could customize the pickle file at *pickling* time, with a `__getstate__` method, and store the the new `Baz` class in the serialized file - and building an intermediate version that would feature both classes and do this conversion is feasible.

Or, what is easier in this case, is just create the class with some mechanism to remap the nested class name, at Unpickle time - I think it would require a metaclass with a `__getattr__` - it will be called at unpickle time with the name of the class that was not found nested in "Foo", and can just return the newly created class instead:

```
class M(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, attr):
        if attr == "Bar":
            return getattr(cls, "Baz")
        raise AttributeError()

class Foo(metaclass=M):
    class Baz:
        def __init__(self, _):
            pass  # Imagine some implementation

    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = Foo.Baz(a)
```

The "Foo" instance above can unpickle a similar class that was serialized with the inner class being named "Bar" instead.  Of course, if there are several instances of this, you can just use a mapping inside the metaclass' `__getattr__` instead of a hard-coded "if"